# autoHideDuration is not working in Snackbar using hook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I am using a @material-ui snackbar in numerous places within my reactjs project; however, this has resulted in duplication of code when it comes to the onClose and onClick handlers. So I have decided to move the parameters to a hook. Subsequently, when I created the hook and moved the code over, autoHideDuration stopped working. I am curious as to why?

I have tried moving the Snackbar component into the hook and rendering the complete snackbar with parameters but that also did not work.

At this point I just made a custom component that encases the snackbar component and handlers and import the custom component throughout my project. Never-the-less, I still would like to figure a solution as to why autoHideDuration stopped working in the first solution

I have included a code sandbox below with the erroneous behavior:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-chaplygin-z2jr5nqry3?fontsize=14

Expected result: the snackbar should close automatically after the defined timeout period set in autoHideDuration in the useSnackbar.js file

Comment: Please copy relevant code into your StackOverflow question so others can help. You're more likely to get an answer if the majority of your code is hosted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with `handleClose` event. You are using object destructing `({ event, reason })` of one argument, but it must be two separate arguments `(event, reason)`.

This is how your `handleClose` should look:

```
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
        return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
};
```